# When stacking filters, how much larger than the lens thread diameter should they be to avoid vignetting?

Tags: filters, long-exposure, polarizer, neutral-density, vignetting

I want to do long exposure photography but I am not willing to shell the dollars for a good 100mm filter kit.

I am now considering a cheaper solution using circular filters. I want to be able to shoot without vignetting at 17mm with my 17-55mm Canon APS-C lens. The thread diameter is 77mm.

What filter diameter should I purchase in order to be able to stack two filters without producing vignetting? ("the largest the better" not a helpful answer).

The combinations I am planning to use are

- single stopper (4 or 10 stops)
- one stopper plus one circular polarizer

The stoppers are 5.5mm thick. The circular polarizer I am currently looking at is 7.5mm but I'd rather use one that's 4.5mm thick. My filters would thus have max thickness of 10mm to 13mm.

Comment: How do you plan to attach the filters to the lens?

Comment: By "circular filters" you mean "circular polarizing filters", right? I've edited with that assumption.

Comment: But there's _another_ assumption I'm unclear on. A good circular polarizer will not be meaningfully (if at all) cheaper than a good ND filter. A _larger_ circular polarizer will probably be much more expensive. Why not just get one filter meant for the task at hand?

Comment: @mattdm I don't think Philippe was necessarily referring to circular _polarizers_ per se. In 1st paragraph, he said he wasn't willing to buy a _100mm filter kit_, as in 100mm × 100mm _square_ filter kit. Instead he just wanted to buy screw-on (round) filters. Probably should have said _round_ rather than circular.

Comment: @scottbb Maybe? I guess I'm voting for "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: As he refers to a 100mm filter kit I assume he means rectangular filters that fit into some frame. In contrast to those, circular filters are those which are screwed directly onto the lens.

Comment: Circular and round are synonymous for me. Circular does not imply polarized. There are many other kinds of circular filters.

Answer (score 2):

According to a FOV calculator, 17mm gives a 76.2 degree diagonal FOV for Canon APS-C sensors. That's an angle of 38.1 degrees either side of straight ahead.

<s>Sin(38.1) = 0.617+ so for each mm forward, a light ray at the edge of the FOV goes sideways by a bit over 0.617mm.</s>

You probably need to add a few mm for a step up ring to attach the bigger filters to the camera, so lets say 3mm for that, giving you a range of 13 to 16mm.

<s>13mm gives 8.02mm extra needed on each side = 93.04mm, and 16mm gives 9.87mm extra needed on each side = 96.75mm</s>

Since standard sizes are 82, 86, 95, and 112mm, you'd probably want to go for 95mm (which might give you slight vignetting on the corners with thicker filters - it depends whether the original 77mm is actually needed, or whether that's just the closest standard size over the actual requirement), or 112mm.

[Edit - just realised I got the trig wrong - sideways distance should be tan (= opposite / adjacent) rather than sin (= opposite / hypotenuse).

tan(38.1) = 0.7841 so for each mm forward, a light ray at the edge of the FOV goes sideways by a bit over 0.7841 mm.
This gives 10.193 mm per side for 13mm thickness , = 97.387mm,  and 12.546 mm per side for 16mm thickness = 102.09mm.

However, the original 77mm is presumably chosen to work with a single filter
so if you reduce the effective thickness to compensate for that, you're somewhat better off - if you knock 3mm off (which is probably conservative) you're back to 92.682 mm for 10mm thickess so 95mm is probably OK ]

Comment: And when the OP sees the price of most quality 95mm filters they'll likely realize why most shooters using similar lenses use 100mm filters.

Answer (score 0):

Search the web for gelatin neutral density filters. They are inexpensive and plus the quality is high. Get a 10 stop square gel and tape it over your camera lens. Try this, you will like it!

Comment: YES; but, gelatin filters are not as cheap as they used to be! You might want to get and use a filter holder to preserve your gelatin filters instead of tape.